# Would deactivating the Simple 301 Redirects plugin deactivate the 301 redirects themselves?

Tags: plugins

One of the websites I'm working on is on the same domain as a previous version that was built with Magento. Due to this, the Google Search Console found *thousands* of 404 errors. Using the aptly named Simple 301 Redirects plugin however, I've been able to patch these holes in our dinghy, and have submitted the sitemap to the Search Console every time I've gone through and added more redirects, and as of today, it returns only three 404s for desktop and one for mobile.

However, the site in question is getting heinously sluggish, and I suspect that storing or acting on the data for this plugin is partly responsible for this, so I would like to either deactivate it for the time being or clear its contents. Will doing either of these deactivate the 301 redirects? And do I have to worry about deactivating them if I have submitted my sitemap?

Comment: It takes a while for google to update the indexed page. I changed my permalink structure and it took like 6 month for my URLs to be fully updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, the redirects will no longer exist if you deactivate the plugin.

I've just manually checked in the plugin's files. Your redirects get saved to a option named `301_redirects`, the plugin then hooks into `init` with its `redirect()` function, which does what it is named after.

This means once you deactivate the plugin, this option won't be checked anymore and more importantly, no redirects will be issued.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I'll have to keep it on then. Thank you!